# Avoid series points overlapping in dxChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, devexpress, devextreme

[Marion's](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q567706) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86SW5/28/), which perfectly shows multiple distinct points for multiple series.

Following this, I'm trying to implement the same in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/c869jfef/).

I have 2 `Name` fields `PaidDataAxis` and `DeniedDataAxis`

I'm returning series based on this only:

```
customizeSeries: function(seriesName) {
  if (seriesName === 'PaidDataAxis') {
    return {
      axis: 'paid'
    }
  } else {
    return {
      axis: 'denied'
    }
  }
}
```

`MarkerType` which is a `tagField` is not required.

Both the series along with their points are getting rendered. However, I see that the points are overlapping.

> How to avoid series points overlapping in `dxChart` in this case?

There's something stupid I'm doing, but unable to figure out where.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in such case is to apply `min` on [`valueAxis`](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxChart/Configuration/valueAxis/?version=16_1#min) and/or [`argumentAxis`](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxChart/Configuration/argumentAxis/?version=16_1#min)

```
valueType: 'numeric', //for staying safer
min: 0,
```

Without which, `dxChart` will try to automatically calculate axes' scale